# Can we upgrade apk with same signed keystore but from different desktop in android

Tags: android

This is Manoj.

I have developed one application and that is uploaded to Play Store. I have saved the keystore in my desktop. Now I am modifying the source code from different Desktop and When I am trying to make update apk with that same keystore it is saying SH1 fingerprint changed.

Can't I upgrade the application from different Desktop by using existing keystore???

Help!

Comment: Yes, it can & For your case please make sure that your `signed keystore` is same.

Answer (score -1):

You can upload your build from different system there is no any issue. but you have to user same keystore file.
and during upload it should not say fingerprint changed like this error.

I think in your app having facebook login, so make your system SHA1 key is added on facebook.

Comment: I have not used fb login..any way fb login is a feature in android app..how that will prevent to upload the update apk in play store...??

Comment: ye, it should not impact, but i am doing i have upload apk from different different system. i i am not getting any problem.